# Dimension of a set of matrices whose trace is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, trace

Let $\mathcal V$ be a vector space whose elements are matrices of **zero trace**.

What is the **dimension** of $\mathcal V$ and why?

Comment: There are $n^2$ entries of the matrix, and you are imposing one linear condition. So the dimension is $n^2-1$.

Answer (score 5):

The trace is a non-zero linear functional ${\rm tr}\colon {\rm Mat}(n,\Bbb K) \to \Bbb K$. We know that $$\dim_{\Bbb K} {\rm Mat}(n, \Bbb K) = \dim_{\Bbb K} \ker {\rm tr} + \dim_{\Bbb K} {\rm Im}\,{\rm tr},$$so $\dim_{\Bbb K} \ker {\rm tr} = n^2 - 1$.